# Where is the documentation for transaction specification in Solana for JSON RPC API?

Tags: solana, solana-transaction-instruction

I need to submit transactions from a server program to Solana blockchain for processing.

My programs is not JavaScript, therefore, I cannot use web3js.

I use the JSON RPC API sendTransaction:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#sendtransaction

I need to form the transaction in the program.

Where is the documentation for transaction specification for various types, eg. transfer, approve, revoke, etc?

Eg.
How do I form a "transfer" transaction? What's the spec for that? What parameters are required and their names and types?

Best regards,
Configentia

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a signed transaction locally first using the [transfer](https://docs.solana.com/offline-signing#example-offline-signing-a-payment) instruction then encode it as a string and send it in sendTransaction

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "sendTransaction",
    "params": [
      "4hXTCkRzt9WyecNzV1XPgCDfGAZzQKNxLXgynz5QDuWWPSAZBZSHptvWRL3BjCvzUXRdKvHL2b7yGrRQcWyaqsaBCncVG7BFggS8w9snUts67BSh3EqKpXLUm5UMHfD7ZBe9GhARjbNQMLJ1QD3Spr6oMTBU6EhdB4RD8CP2xUxr2u3d6fos36PD98XS6oX8TQjLpsMwncs5DAMiD4nNnR8NBfyghGCWvCVifVwvA8B8TJxE1aiyiv2L429BCWfyzAme5sZW8rDb14NeCQHhZbtNqfXhcp2tAnaAT"
    ]
  }
```

I'm not sure how you can create a signed transaction locally without a solana package, maybe you can but it would be a lot harder, solana has sdks for python, js/ts, golang, java, rust, c++

Comment: Thanks Anoushk, noted that Solana only provides sdks for Rust and JS at the moment. So I'll try with JS first. Thank you.